# Views Custom field sort not working

Tags: 7, views

I have created custom views handler for adding custom field in view. I have used code below to create custom handler.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data().
 */
 function my_module_views_data() {
   $data['custom']['table']['group'] = t('Custom');
   $data['custom']['table']['join'] = array(
     // #global is a special flag which let's a table appear all the time.
     '#global' => array(),
   );

   $data['custom']['custom_handler'] = array(
     'title' => t('Custom Handler'),
     'help' => t('Custom Handler.'),
     'field' => array(
       'handler' => 'views_handler_custom_handler',
       'click sortable' => TRUE,
     ),
   );

   return $data;
}

/**
 * A handler to provide a field that is completely custom by the administrator.
 *
 * @ingroup views_field_handlers
 */
 class views_handler_custom_handler extends views_handler_field {
   function query() {
     // do nothing -- to override the parent query.
   }

   function option_definition() {
     $options = parent::option_definition();

     // Override the alter text option to always alter the text.
     $options['alter']['contains']['alter_text'] = array('default' => TRUE);
     return $options;
   }

   function options_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
     parent::options_form($form, $form_state);

     // Remove the checkbox
     unset($form['alter']['alter_text']);
     unset($form['alter']['text']['#dependency']);
     unset($form['alter']['text']['#process']);
   }

   function render($values) {
     // Render your content.
      $download_count = db_query("SELECT count(cl.id) FROM {custom_table} cl")->fetchField();
 // Render your content.
 return $download_count;;
   }
}
```

Above code shows the custom field in view. I have added the field in view and rendered the view in **table** format and enable sortable option for custom field but it not sortable and throws the below error.

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'unknown' in
> 'order clause'

Kindly share correct way to do this.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same problem.